# My package doesn't support Windows Server (Chocolatey test environment): how do I "skip" the install, so the automatic testing doesn't fail?

Tags: chocolatey

My package can't be installed on Windows Server, simply doesn't support it.

I have submitted my package to Chocolatey repository, but tests are failing. The automatic test fail for that reason, because the test environment of Chocolatey is based on Windows Server (can't remember which version).

Is there a way to fix this and get the package published? How I can tell to "pass the test" or "skip the test" because the package isn't supposed to support that OS?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to request exemption from what is known as the package-verifier (this is the automated system that attempts to install your package, prior to getting it approved).

This can be done via the package moderation comments on the package page.

Create a comment on the package page, explaining why your package should be exempted, and one of the human moderators will pick it up, and will provide the exemption (assuming that there aren't any other issues with your package).